# Fetch Logged in User Converstations From Twilio converations Rest Api

Tags: twilio-conversations

Am utilizing the rest Api to fetch conversations.
The problem a facing now is that am getting all conversations that am not involved in.
I need the get only those that i have created or those that i have been added into.

```
curl -X GET "https://conversations.twilio.com/v1/Conversations?" \
-u "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```